# Is it possible to check if an item from a list exists in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

So, I am trying to make a very basic chatbot, and I wanted to create a list of possible user inputs, and then a variable that takes the user input and converts it in a string. So far, so good. What I cannot achieve, and I am not even sure that this is possible or not, is to have my program to check whether the user input includes some phrase from the list and then provide an answer via an if statement.

I tried something like:

```
a = ["hello","hey","hi"]

command= str(input())

if a in command:
  print("Hi!")
```

Of course, it didn't work, because the "a" had to be a string. What I wanted to happen was for the program to check if the word hello, hey, or hi, is in the command variable, and if it is, to print "Hi!". I want it to work like this would:

if "hello" in command or "hi" in command or "hey" in command
  print("Hi!")

What can I do about it?

Comment: `if command in a` should work

Comment: Might be worth looking into `any()` and `all()`

Comment: @NicoT Yeah, but isn;t that the oposite? I mean, I want it to work even if the user input was "hello there". The "hello" of the phrase is still in the list, so the response will occur. But by checking if the value of the "command" variable is in the string, woyldn't get me a respone, because  the phrase "hello there" is not a part of the list...

Comment: @eROF you are right, I missread the question. Check my answer below.

Comment: Alright, thanks for that, it made it more clear, I edited my asnwer to adapt it to your comment, it should be good to go now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you want to achieve, but let's say you want to check if any of the elements in `a` should be in the `command` variable, you can use the following:

```
any(e in command for e in a)
```

Example:

```
>>> command = 'this is a command hello'
>>> any(e in command for e in a)
True
>>> command = 'will give you false'
>>> any(e in command for e in a)
False
>>> command = 'hi hello hey'
>>> any(e in command for e in a)
True
```

Therefore your code should be as follows:

```
a = ["hello","hey","hi"]

command= str(input())

if any(e in command for e in a):
  print("Hi!")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve!! Thank you so much, it worked!! :D

Answer (score 2):

```
for w in a:
    if w in command:
        print("Hi!)
```

for word in `a`, if command contains the word, then you print "Hi!".

This will work even with strings that start with Hi or Hello and then have some more text that follows.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ["hello","hey","hi"]

command = 'hello there, general Kenobi'

any(map(lambda x: x in command, a))
Output[]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
a = ["hello","hey","hi"]

command= str(input())

if command in a: #Simple change here
   print("Hi!")
```

Comment: From the OP: "check whether the user input includes some phrase from the list". I read this as checking that any one of the words in the list is a substring of `command`. Your solution requires that the input be exactly one of the words in the list instead.

Comment: You are right, we should just use the split function on the input and check if any word is in the "a" list. We should also be careful at any punctuation that may cause failure in our code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set for checking inclusion, and you have your if statement backwards. You're wondering if the user said a greeting not if a greeting was in what the user said. Simpler logic this way.

```
greetings = {"hello", "hey", "hi"}

command = str(input())

if command in greetings:
  print("Hi!")
```

Comment: From the OP: "check whether the user input includes some phrase from the list". I read this as checking that any one of the words in the list is a substring of `command`. Your solution requires that the input be exactly one of the words in the list instead.

Comment: It did not work, unfortunately...
I wanted it to respont even if the input was not one of the three words, but included one of them

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you are trying to do, and also, help you solve a loop problem for the input does not match the desired one! By using `while` I'm requiring the user to input `'hi', 'hey' or 'hello'` to further advance in the bots program. Try it and let me know if there's any other questions to further improve this answer!

```
a = ["hello","hey","hi"]

command = str(input())
while any(map(lambda w: w in command, a)) == False:
    print("What did you say?")
    command = str(input())
print("Well hello there!")
```

EDIT: Corrected interpretation mistake as comment said.

I even had some fun with it:

```
Input: eee
Output: What did you say?
Input: I said hello!
Output: Well hello there!
```

Comment: From the OP: "check whether the user input includes some phrase from the list". I read this as checking that any one of the words in the list is a substring of `command`. Your solution requires that the input be exactly one of the words in the list instead.

Comment: You are correct, OP clarified it in a comment, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> have my program to check whether the user input includes some phrase from the list

Let's break this into smaller steps. We will us plain English rather than strict Python syntax. But at the same time, we want to use constructs that are easily translated into Python later. For example, we can use words like "for" and "if" that will translate directly into their python equivalents.

```
for each phrase from a list of allowed commands
    if phrase is in user command that was input
        do the thing
```

Notice how we are using constructs that look like `for` and `if` statements. When we describe a solution in this way, it becomes easier to translate it into a programming language. At the same time, you shouldn't overly worried about Python syntax so that you can focus on the logic of the solution rather than the programming details.

Once you understand how to write these kinds of loops, you can start to learn about list comprehensions and functions like `any()` or `all()` that can be used to write this solution more concisely.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying : D
I will try it~